# Looking back at previous row in data-frame and selecting specific records

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which looks like:

```
           name     year    dept         metric
0   Steve Jones     2018       A    0.703300236
1   Steve Jones     2019       A    0.255587222
2   Jane Smith      2018       A    0.502505934
3   Jane Smith      2019       B    0.698808749
4   Barry Evans     2019       B    0.941325241
5   Tony Edwards    2017       B    0.880940126
6   Tony Edwards    2018       B    0.649086123
7   Tony Edwards    2019       A    0.881365905
```

I would like to create 2 new data-frame which contains the records where someone has moved from dept A to B and and another where someone has moved from dept B to A.  Therefore my desired output is:

```
            name        year    dept         metric
0     Jane Smith        2018       A    0.502505934
1     Tony Edwards      2019       B    0.649086123

            name        year    dept         metric
0     Jane Smith        2019       B    0.698808749
1   Tony Edwards        2018       B    0.881365905
```

Where records for the year the last year that someone is in their old dept are captured in one data-frame and the first year in the new dept are captured in another only. The records are sorted by name and year so will be in the correct order.

I've tried :

```
for row in agg_data.rows:

    df['match'] = np.where(df.dept == 'A' and  df.dept.shift() =='B','1')
    df['match'] = np.where(df.dept == 'B' and  df.dept.shift() =='A','2')
```

and then select out the records into a data-frame but I get it to work.

Comment: The first df you've shown doesn't seem to match your explanation... can you clarify?

Comment: Why years and dept are changed in expected output if compare by rows with input data? Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df = df[df.groupby('name')['dept'].transform('nunique') > 1]
df = df.drop_duplicates(['name','dept'], keep='last')

df1 = df.drop_duplicates('name')
print (df1)
           name  year dept    metric
2    Jane Smith  2018    A  0.502506
6  Tony Edwards  2018    B  0.649086

df2 = df.drop_duplicates('name', keep='last')
print (df2)
           name  year dept    metric
3    Jane Smith  2019    B  0.698809
7  Tony Edwards  2019    A  0.881366
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join the initial dataframe with a shift of itself to have convecutive rows on same line. Then you ask the departments you want requiring the names to be the same and you get the indices of one of the expected rows, the other row just has an adjacent index. It gives:

```
df = agg_data.join(agg_data.shift(), rsuffix='_old')

df1 = df[(df.name_old==df.name)&(df.dept_old=='A')&(df.dept=='B')]
print(pd.concat([agg_data.loc[df1.index], agg_data.loc[df1.index-1]]
                ).sort_index())

df2 = df[(df.name_old==df.name)&(df.dept_old=='B')&(df.dept=='A')]
print(pd.concat([agg_data.loc[df2.index], agg_data.loc[df2.index-1]]
                ).sort_index())
```

with following output:

```
         name  year dept    metric
2  Jane Smith  2018    A  0.502506
3  Jane Smith  2019    B  0.698809
           name  year dept    metric
6  Tony Edwards  2018    B  0.649086
7  Tony Edwards  2019    A  0.881366
```

Answer (score 0):

I come up with a solution using `drop_duplicates`, `groupby` and `rank`. Creating `df2` on `rank=2` and creating `df1` on `rank==1` and `name` exists in `df2`

```
df['rk'] = df.sort_values(['name', 'dept', 'year']).drop_duplicates(['name', 'dept'], keep='last').groupby('name').year.rank()
df2 = df[df.rk.eq(2)].drop('rk', 1)
df1 = df[df.rk.eq(1) & df.name.isin(df2.name)].drop('rk', 1)


df1:
           name  year dept    metric
2    Jane Smith  2018    A  0.502506
6  Tony Edwards  2018    B  0.649086

df2:
           name  year dept    metric
3    Jane Smith  2019    B  0.698809
7  Tony Edwards  2019    A  0.881366
```